# WIQL Query on WorkItemLinks

Tags: c#, tfs, wiql, azure-devops-rest-api

The TFS API implements this class:

﻿[image]

How can I use a WIQL query and the TFS API to get all work items who have had a parent/child link added or changed since a given date? I would suspect using the WorkItemLinks table would be a place to start, but I have found little to no documentation on the supplied fields. Also, it is important to note that changing a work item link does not affect the work item's changed date field. I suspect that is because links have their own changed/created date fields. I'm looking to get these items in a flat list view. What are my options?**

Comment: I have updated my reply, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to help you. Using the workitem query to find those workitems seems couldn't do that. But you could use this method: Find each workitems' workitemLinks, check if its link type is "parent/child" and check if its added/removed date is during your time period .

```
var workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var queryString = @"select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] 
                    from WorkItemLinks 
                    where (
                            Source.[System.TeamProject] = 'Mtt-Scrum' 
                            and Source.[System.WorkItemType] <> ''
                        ) and (
                            [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward' 
                            or [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse'
                        ) and (
                            Target.[System.TeamProject] = 'Mtt-Scrum' 
                            and Target.[System.WorkItemType] <> ''
                        ) 
                    order by [System.Id] mode (MustContain)";

// Create and run the query.
var query = new Query(workItemStore, queryString);
WorkItemLinkInfo[] witLinkInfos = query.RunLinkQuery();

foreach (WorkItemLinkInfo witinfo in witLinkInfos)
{
    if (witinfo.SourceId == 0)  //find those workitems which are not at top-level
    {
        int targetWIid = witinfo.TargetId;
        WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(targetWIid); //get the workitem
        foreach (WorkItemLink wiLink in workItem.WorkItemLinks)
        {

            if (wiLink.LinkTypeEnd.Name.Equals("Parent") || wiLink.LinkTypeEnd.Name.Equals("Child"))
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(wiLink.AddedDate, 'yourDate') < 0)
                {
                  ......
                }

            }
        }
    }          

}
```